# Significance between sums of groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have an experiment where I am applying 3 different treatments to three separate groups. One of the variables I am trying to assess whether the treatment affecting how much money a user spent per unit of observation. I don't really care about how much they spend per observation, but rather the sum total of all money spent by users per treatment. How can I tell if these 3 cumulative values (1 for each treatment) are significantly different? The cumulative amounts are different and I can observe a trend, but how do reject/fail to reject the hypothesis with a statistic test in this case?

Comment: Once you add up the values, how many observations do you have per group?

Comment: @Dave I have 1,000 obervations per treatment group. When I add up to values per group, I have 3 cumulative values.